# Additional 'Draft' watermark using printwatermark and xwatermark packages

Tags: compiling, backgrounds, watermark, xwatermark

I am using the packages printwatermark and xwatermark to add a watermark in background this way:

```
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
...
\newwatermark[allpages,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{TEST}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

If I compile just once, there is no problem. But If I re-compile without deleting auxiliary files previously generated (for example the toolchain Latex-Bibtex-Latex) then I get an additional watermark 'Draft' in background. But I did not define it anywhere in my file...

[image]

I tried to modify the way I define my watermark like:

```
\newwatermark[allpages,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0, textmark=TEST]{}
```

for example, and to define it inside `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` but the problem is still there.

Does anybody already encountered this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that I was using the additional package

```
\usepackage{background}
```

Removing this line solves the problem.

**So if the packages `printwatermark` and `xwatermark` are used, the `background` package should not be.**

Comment: Most of the time, trying to create a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/64454) leads to the solution without having to wait for an answer (-; Glad you answer your issue!