# xwatermark prints stamp instead of watermark

Tags: compiling, backgrounds, watermark, xwatermark

When using the `xwatermark` package, I'm getting a watermark that is best described as a **stamp**, it has no transparency and is situated over everything else instead of being discretely at the back.

[image]

I'm using a variation of the `mitthesis.cls`, that is suited to the university I'm studying at.
I added `\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}` in my main.tex after `\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{mitthesis}` and amongst the other packages I'm importing.

I've placed `\newwatermark[allpages,color=blue!2,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT}` both before and after the `\begin{document}` tag, but get the same result.

I'm not using the `background` package, so the discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301504/additional-draft-watermark-using-printwatermark-and-xwatermark-packages/301722) hasn't helped, even though I tried the alternative way of calling up `newwatermark`.

Has anyone experienced this problem and corrected it?

Comment: Which engine do you use for the compilation?

Comment: texStudio with MacTex

Comment: Texstudio is only the editor. Make a small complete example the shows the problem, if possible it should use the article class and not your class and show it along with the log-file.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, I will need to do some juggling here.  I was hoping someone who has used the MIT Thesis template would come across this question.  There is some sort of conflict between it and the `xwatermark` package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I worked out why I was having the problem.  See my proposed answer below.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was related to the fact that `xwatermark`, uses, but does not load, the `xcolor` package.  I needed `\usepackage{xcolor}` to get it working.
It may be possible to use `xwatermark` without this package, say if the watermark is a graphic, but I'm not in a position, strictly speaking due to lack of experience, to comment.

> With the xcolor package (not loaded automatically by the xwatermark
>   package), all colors (in- cluding white, shades like -red!75!green!50,
>   and those defined within the user document) can be passed to this
>   package. And, as mentioned above, both texts and pictures can be
>   submitted and printed as watermarks on the same page, and on different
>   positions.

*I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer for now, but will select another one if/when I see an answer that gives a better explanation.*

Comment: I am not sure you will get any other answer since you did not provide any MWE allowing to reproduce your issue